# Convert string to date using strtotime php

Tags: php, date, strtotime

please i need help in converting string to date

my string is `$search = '6/2/2014'`

i used this way but it doesn't work correctly

```
$time = strtotime('$search');

$newformat = date('DD-MM-YYYY',$time);

echo $newformat;
```

the result is  displayed as `01-01-70`  What should I do for this output help.

Comment: use $time = strtotime($search); // $search ='6/2/2014';

Comment: Remove the quotes! Your string is literally "$search", not your `$search` variable.

Comment: `$newformat = date('DD-MM-YYYY', strtotime($search));`

Comment: He is using strtotime(),  just lack of knowledge... why downvotes????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all **DON'T** use `strtotime` as it is unreliable. Use the new `DateTime` class. In your case use something like this:

```
$time = DateTime::createFromFormat('m/d/Y', $search, new DateTimeZone('America/New_York'));
$newformat = $time->format('d-m-Y');
echo $newformat;
```